# How can I create a straight line tool with the Markups Extension?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have been using the markups extension for a while to persist annotations on the viewer. But, one request I have had is for a straight line tool, and I would think this is something that is already implemented. Is this undocumented, and a possibility? If not, is there a straight-forward way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the markup extension does not provide this feature.  I am submitting a request to the viewing team.